# How to call a spring controller at every specific time intervals?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, postgresql

Hey I have this web application set up with spring and postgres. Assume my application allows a user to make some reservation by specifying a time. If he does not show up within half an hour from the specified time I want to cancel this reservation. So assume the table where I'm storing the reservations contains a column with values of the specified reservation time and a boolean flag that indicates whether the user has arrived or not.

I can think of two ways to handle this scenario. One would be to create a spring controller that can check the values from the reservation table and see if the difference between the current time and the specified time is greater than half an hour and if it is then cancel the reservation. The other way is to create some postgres function that can achieve the same.

I want somebody to help me here. How do I repeatedly call the above mentioned spring controller at every time interval of say 15 minutes? Or if writing a postgres function that reduces the workload of the application how do I do this?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
SerotoninChase

Comment: Do you have access to cron (or equivalent) on your server?

Comment: This is the first time I'm hearing something called cron. I just realized I'm so far behind.

Comment: [cron](http://clickmojo.com/code/cron-tutorial.html) is the standard unix program for running tasks at periodic intervals. Everyone is behind at some point, don't worry about it, just keep learning :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could annotate the method you wish to be called with `@Scheduled(fixedRate=900000)`, this is a spring annotation to call that method every 15 minutes.

Check out the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#scheduling-annotation-support-scheduled).

Comment: Damn I've never tried using annotations. Okay let me read on that and then try out your solution. Thank you for your answer though.

Comment: Ok I went through the documentation. I have a doubt now. Lets say I used the annotation you mentioned above. My understanding is that the method will be called every fifteen minutes. But this method is inside a spring controller. So is it just enough that I call this controller once and method keeps repeatedly running every 15 minutes? And if the controller is called again will it cause a problem?

Comment: It runs every fifteen minutes from the start-up of the program. So just write a method to check all entries in the reservation table and cancel the appropriate ones.

Answer (score 3):

Just please be sure that the method annotated with @Scheduled must not be a method annotated with @RequestMapping as well:

> Notice that the methods to be scheduled must have void returns and
>   must not expect any arguments.

And you need @EnableScheduling in your configuration class